# How to sort strings in an 2D array in C

Tags: c, sorting, multidimensional-array

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int N, i, j, k, z, v, x, c;

printf("Determine the number of your words: \n");
scanf("%d", &N);
char dict[N][50];
char tmp[50];
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    printf("Determine your %d. word: \n", i+1);
    scanf("%49s", &dict[i]);
}




for(j=1; j<N; j++)
{
    k=j;
    z=0;
    while(dict[j][z]!= '\0')
    {
        tmp[z]=dict[j][z];
        z=z+1;
    }

    
    while((dict[j][1]<dict[k-1][1]) && (k>0))
    {
        v=0;
        while(dict[k][v]!= '\0')
        {
            dict[k][v] = dict[k-1][v];
            v= v+1;
        }
        k=k-1;
    }
    x=0;
    while(dict[k][x]!= '\0')
    {
        dict[k][x]=tmp[x];
        x=x+1;
    }
    
}


for(c=0; c<N; c++)
{
    
    printf("%s \n", dict[c]);
    
}



return 0;
```

}

So as a junior CE student our task is to write a C code that sort the strings in a 2D array according to their first characters position in the alphabet by only using the <stdio.h> library and this is the result I get is below(I know the variables are not really bearable but I'm in a little bit of a hurry):

```
Determine the number of your words:
5
Determine your 1. word:
LION
Determine your 2. word:
FISH
Determine your 3. word:
TIGER
Determine your 4. word:
SNAKE
Determine your 5. word:
SEALION
LION
FISH
TIGER
SEALI
SNAKE
```

I get no errors just the result is faulty and I do not wish any answers. But I would be glad to be enlightened about the reasons I get this results

Comment: If not allowed to use `strcmp()` and `strcpy()`, I'd probably write my own functions for those tasks.

Comment: I tried to do that by swapping(changing the places of the second and the firs string)

Comment: Why rewrite subtle variations of the code in multiple places? And it's easier to understand the code if you are calling well-named functions instead of having to figure out what each `while` loop does.

Comment: Again, it's my first semestr in college and we haven't really procceded on the terms of coding(which is the subject of the second semestr) so we don't create our own functions yet

Comment: try to explain in english how are you trying to sort (what you think the could should do)

Comment: I think one issue is `while((dict[j][1]<dict[k-1][1]) && (k>0))`. The `[1]` should probably be `[0]` (C uses zero-based indexing). Also, you should put `k>0` *first*, so short circuiting prevents accessing outside the array boundaries.

Comment: AND HERE IS OUR WINNING ANSWER :D CODE WORKED. I cannot believe I missed that. Thank you very much. But Sealion doesn't come out full. It comes as Seali. I don't know why.

Comment: @MahmutMahmudov: I solved it. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comparison is incorrect:

```
while((dict[j][1]<dict[k-1][1]) && (k>0))
```

First, if you want to compare the first character of each word, use `[0]` instead of `[1]`. This is because array indexes are zero-based in C. Second, put the `k>0` comparison first, before you use `k-1` as an index to the array. This will take advantage of "short circuiting" to make sure you're not using an invalid index to the array. Result:

```
while(k > 0 && dict[j][0] < dict[k-1][0])
```

Another issue is that you are not making sure your strings are null terminated when you copy them. I believe this is the reason your "SEALION" is coming out "SEALI".  For example, this loop:

```
x=0;
while(dict[k][x]!= '\0')
{
    dict[k][x]=tmp[x];
    x=x+1;
}
```

You're checking for null on the destination instead of the source. Also, you stop copying at the null character, but you actually need to copy that too, or at least tack a null at the end:

```
x=0;
while(tmp[x]!= '\0')
{
    dict[k][x]=tmp[x];
    x=x+1;
}
dict[k][x] = '\0';
```

Take a close look at each of your string copy loops for such errors.

Comment: that is the answer I was looking for. It hurts that such mistakes can ruin the whole code. Thanks you.

Comment: Such is the nature of programming. If this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the gray check mark under the answer score.

Comment: With this input it did solve my problem but a new problem occured that when I gave more input with mix order the result was not fully solved such as:
Determine the number of your words:
10
Determine your 1. word:
FISH
Determine your 2. word:
LION
Determine your 3. word:
SNAKE
Determine your 4. word:
LOPRICON
Determine your 5. word:
TIGER
Determine your 6. word:
SEALION
Determine your 7. word:
FRAG
Determine your 8. word:
GRENADE
Determine your 9. word:
SUPERMAN
Determine your 10. word:
MAGICIAN
FISH
LION
LOPRICON
SNAKE
SEALION
FRAG
GRENADE
SUPERMAN
MAGICIAN
TIGE

Comment: There are flaws in your sort algorithm. Try studying the [bubble sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) to see where it goes astray.

Comment: I've posted a new question with the same topic but I used bubblesort this time. I would be glad if you could take a peak at it. link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65344720/how-to-write-a-c-code-that-bubblesorts-the-strings-in-a-2d-array

Answer (score 1):

**Limited to `stdio.h`**

If you are limited to using what is provided in `stdio.h`, then you simply have to write similar string handling functionality to what you would require from `string.h`. For sorting, unless you want to use a partitioning sort like quicksort or mergesort, you would be limited to a nested loop sort -- which are simpler to write -- but much much slower. (but for a 1000 or so strings, it doesn't matter, 100,000 - then there will be a perceivable difference)

To compare strings, you can write a simple `strcmp()` like function that requires no additional header, e.g.

```
/** string compare without string.h */
int strcmp_nohdr (const char *a, const char *b)
{
    if (!a && !b) return 0;
    if ( a && !b) return 1;
    if (!a &&  b) return -1;

    for (; *a && *a == *b; a++, b++) {}

    return (*a > *b) - (*a < *b);
}
```

If you are not declaring an additional set of pointers to sort, then you will need to copy strings between the rows (1D arrays) in your 2D array. You can write a simple `strcpy()` like function that needs no header as:

```
/** string copy wihout string.h */
char *strcpy_nohdr (char *dest, const char *src)
{
    char *p = dest;
    
    do {
        *p++ = *src;
    } while (*src++);
    
    return dest;
}
```

Finally, the only other thing you need is a sort function. (you will not be able to write a quick `qsort()` replacement) The meager *Bubblesort* will do. You can write a function to sort your 2D array of strings as:

```
#define NCHR 50

/** bubble sort of strings in 'a' (highly inefficient) */
void bubblesort2D (char (*a)[NCHR], size_t n)
{
    size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < (n-1); j++) {
            if (strcmp_nohdr(a[j], a[j + 1]) > 0) {
                char temp[NCHR];
                strcpy_nohdr (temp, a[j + 1]);
                strcpy_nohdr  (a[j + 1], a[j]);
                strcpy_nohdr  (a[j], temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you put those altogether in a short example (the same used before with `qsort()`, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NCHR 50

/** string compare without string.h */
int strcmp_nohdr (const char *a, const char *b)
{
    if (!a && !b) return 0;
    if ( a && !b) return 1;
    if (!a &&  b) return -1;

    for (; *a && *a == *b; a++, b++) {}

    return (*a > *b) - (*a < *b);
}

/** string copy wihout string.h */
char *strcpy_nohdr (char *dest, const char *src)
{
    char *p = dest;
    
    do {
        *p++ = *src;
    } while (*src++);
    
    return dest;
}

/** bubble sort of strings in 'a' (highly inefficient) */
void bubblesort2D (char (*a)[NCHR], size_t n)
{
    size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < (n-1); j++) {
            if (strcmp_nohdr(a[j], a[j + 1]) > 0) {
                char temp[NCHR];
                strcpy_nohdr (temp, a[j + 1]);
                strcpy_nohdr  (a[j + 1], a[j]);
                strcpy_nohdr  (a[j], temp);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main (void) {
    
    char strings[][NCHR] = { "zebra", "alligators", "frogs", "racoons", "opossums" };
    size_t n = sizeof strings / sizeof *strings;
    
    bubblesort2D (strings, n);
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        puts (strings[i]);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

The results are the same as before:

```
$ ./bin/sort_2d_strings_stdio
alligators
frogs
opossums
racoons
zebra
```

Since I originally wrote the `qsort()` answer, I'll leave it below as the way you would want to handle sorting (whatever array you are sorting) in practice.

**In Practice Use `qsort()`**

C provides `qsort()` that will sort arrays of any object based on the `compare` function you write to tell `qsort()` how elements of the array are to be compares. With strings, you just want to return the result of `strcmp()`. Each argument to the `compare` function ia a *Pointers* to an element of your array. Since it is a `void*` pointer, you must cast the pointer back to the correct type.

Recall in C that a 2D array is simply *an array of 1D arrays*. In your case it is a array of 50-character arrays. A pointer to an array of 50-chars has the type `char (*)[50]`, so your `qsort()` `compare` function can be written as follows:

```
int cmpstr50 (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char  *pa = *(char (*)[50])a,
                *pb = *(char (*)[50])b;
    
    return strcmp (pa, pb);
}
```

Where each of the parameters is a pointer to an array of `char [50]`. Nothing could be easier. Moreover the algorithm used by `qsort()` will be orders of magnitude faster than what you write with nested loops.

A complete example for your case would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmpstr50 (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char  *pa = *(char (*)[50])a,
                *pb = *(char (*)[50])b;
    
    return strcmp (pa, pb);
}

int main (void) {
    
    char strings[][50] = { "zebra", "alligators", "frogs", "racoons", "opossums" };
    size_t n = sizeof strings / sizeof *strings;
    
    qsort (strings, n, sizeof *strings, cmpstr50);
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        puts (strings[i]);
}
```

Where after writing your `compare` function, all it takes to sort the array of strings (or array of anything) is a single call to `qsort()`:

```
    qsort (strings, n, sizeof *strings, cmpstr50);
```

Much simpler than trying to reinvent the wheel.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/qsort_2d_strings
alligators
frogs
opossums
racoons
zebra
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I appriciate your answer but the problem is I cannot use almost any of this because the only library I'm permitted to use is <stdio.h> :D. I also cannot use any additional functions like int main void. I'm allowed to write code under only int main

Comment: OP is limited to using `<stdio.h>`.  `qsort()` requires `<stdlib.h>` and sometimes `<search.h>`